# Spring boot mysql run db dump code on startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to run the db dump code in the txt file while Spring boot application start. How can i do this?
otherwise i must copy-past and run db dump code to the mysql cli with manually.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to LOAD data to database, i prefer to use **Liquibase**

you can load your data from .csv / .yml / .json / .sql
you can run it either before JPA Create Table or after create table.

So if you have a Team you all can have same data and table

if you want to DUMP your database, use liquibase too,

but why you want to dump your data if you have stable data master and it will automatically created everytime you run your app ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will search the Liquibase. As for your question; it's my school project and I want to deliver my project to the teacher as plug and play.